# Position of not in a question

Tags: grammar, questions, negation

What is the difference between the two wordings and which one is correct?

> (1) Why is past tense **not** used?
>
> (2) Why is **not** past tense used?

Comment: Both are correct, but the second one should be, "Why, is not past tense used?"

Comment: Meanwhile, it is worthwhile to note that by modern-day standards, the second one would almost be more poetic and philosophical because a bit more emphasis has been placed on "why" whereas the first one is the more "natural" and most likely, more common, construction of the question. You may see here for more information: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16585/why-is-this-not-versus-why-is-not-this.

Comment: And lastly, if "is not" were contracted, number two would actually be the only choice: "Why isn't past tense used?" and not, "Why past tense isn't used?"

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I've often heard phrases like "why isn't/hasn't/wasn't" and they confused me, that's why I thought "why is not" is the correct non-contracted counterpart. Now it's clear, thanks!

Comment: @olegst This always irritated me in English too. Why **"Isn't he at home?"**=**"Is he not at home?"** and not **"It not he at home"**? But so says the grammar.

Comment: Heh, I had a feeling, which is why I had thrown in that last comment :D.

Comment: Because "not" has scope over the verb "used", not over "past tense used".

Comment: @BillJ isn't the concept of *scope* only used with clauses. "I think that won't work"(in sub clause)," I don't think that work"(in the main clause)? Never heard that it's used with phrases.

Comment: @user178049 "Scope' of negation is the part of the meaning that is negated. In "He has not got many friends", "not" has scope over the quantifier "many". And in "Not everybody agrees with you", "not" has scope over "everybody".

Answer (score 1):

You can choose either of the two

> Why is past tense not used?

or

> Why isn't past tense used?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you can use both? Answer without explanation might be deleted, because they don't teach the patterns of English language well.

Answer (score 0):

Both are incorrect, but if you inserted the word "the", the first one would be correct, while the second would still be wrong:

(1) Why is **the** past tense not used? (correct)

(2) <strike>Why is not **the** past tense used?</strike> (not correct)

"Not" modifies "used" rather than "the past tense": "Is the past tense used?" "No, the past tense is **not** used." Adding "Why" to the beginning of a sentence pulls the auxiliary verb into second position, but leaves "not" and the other words where they were.

UPDATE: As pointed out by @user3081485, you could also write:

(3) Why isn't the past tense used?

Comment: It might also be useful to mention that the correct informal (and more common) version of (1) is "Why isn't the past tense used?".

Answer (score 0):

> (1) Why is past tense not used?

This is correct, but the sentence places an emphasis on the fact that past tense was not used, and suggests a belief that perhaps it should have been.

> (2) Why is not past tense used?

In this construction, "is not" should be replaced with "isn't."

Comment: +1, though I think you should say "In spoken English, *is not* would normally be contracted to *isn't*".

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct, but the first one sounds more natural. An even better phrase would be, 'why isn't past tense used?', because it flows better.

Answer (score 0):

You know that we have the S-V inversion in most questions in English. In your examples the subject is (@Alan) **the past tense**, so we would invert that and *is*. "Why is the past tense not used?"
However, contractions have to stay together, so we'll invert "the past tense" with the whole contraction: "Why isn't the past tense used?"
See here for a bit more information [Wikipedia on Contractions and Inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_auxiliaries_and_contractions#Contractions_and_inversion).