# word order in the negative infinitive

Tags: word-order, infinitives, negation

Is there any rule that regulates the word order in the negative infinitive form?
If the infinitive follows certain verbs in a sentence, it's clear that it should be 'not+to+inf'. For example, We decided not to go to Paris.

But in some dictionary explanations we can see a different word order: to + not+inf.
Are these patterns interchangeable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position of not in a question.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126380/position-of-not-in-a-question) Also [Position of not in the sentence below](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230581/position-of-not-in-the-sentence-below) and [Position of 'not' in a negative interrogative?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43264/position-of-not-in-a-negative-interrogative) and [Is the phrase “to not” correct in English?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103228/is-the-phrase-to-not-correct-in-english), among others.

Comment: Both are possible. The important thing is that the negator "not" has scope over, and modifies, the infinitival clause or its VP.